# Calculating with marginal and conditional densities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Given the r.v. $N$ and $K$ such that $N$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Furthermore let the conditional distribution of $K$ on $N$ be given by
>
> $$ f_{K \mid N} (k \mid n) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $$
>
> What is the expectation $E[K \mid N], E[K]$ and $E[N \mid K]$?

I thought for the first one that

$$ E[K \mid N] = \sum_k k  \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = np$$

For the second one I've thought of using the formula

$$ f_{K \mid N} (k \mid n) = \frac{f_{K,N}(k,n)}{f_N(n)} $$

Therefore:

$$f_{K,N}(k,n) = f_{K \mid N} (k \mid n)f_N(n) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{(n-k)!k!} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $$

Then usually to get the marginal density, I would have to integrate as follows:

$$ f_K(k) = \int f_{K,N}(k,n) dn = \int \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{(n-k)!k!} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

But is this really the right way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Given that $n$ is an integer,  you should sum over $n$ (instead of integrating).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is helpful to keep track of the random variables in your computation. Using majuscules for r.v.'s and minuscule for variables, your first computation reads 
$$E[K \mid N] = \sum_k k  \binom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k} = Np$$
Thus you can use the law of total expectation to get
$$E(K) = E \left[ E (K \mid N) \right] = E [ Np ] = \lambda p$$